# Faster Python List Comprehension

Tags: python

I have a bit of code that runs many thousands of times in my project:

```
def resample(freq, data):
    output = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(freq):
        for _ in range(elem):
            output.append(data[i])
    return output
```

eg. `resample([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` => `['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']`

I want to speed this up as much as possible. It seems like a list comprehension could be faster. I have tried:

```
def resample(freq, data):
   return [item for sublist in [[data[i]]*elem for i, elem in enumerate(frequencies)] for item in sublist]
```

Which is hideous and also slow because it builds the list and then flattens it. Is there a way to do this with one line list comprehension that is fast? Or maybe something with numpy?

Thanks in advance!

edit: Answer does not necessarily need to eliminate the nested loops, fastest code is the best

Comment: List comprehensions are not faster than the equivalent for loops, because they do exactly the same operations.

Comment: Just use `[e for i, e in enumerate(y) for j in range(x[i])]`

Comment: What sort of inputs are you talking about? If the numbers in `freq` are large then perhaps using `extend` in a single loop might be better than `append`

Comment: I don't agree with the closing @jonrsharpe. It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't agree with the closing either.

Comment: I understood the OP to be asking how to write a list comprehension equivalent of nested for loops, which the duplicate does cover. If not, could they please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @jonrsharpe he is not asking that. He is asking how to make the `resample` function which repeats a char based on a list of numbers. My implementation has no nested loops

Comment: In case you are trying to frequency weight data, note that `numpy` and `pandas` are able to deal with weights directly, e.g. to take an average https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html

Comment: @Stuart, `np.average` doesn't work with flexible types like this

Answer (score 5):

I highly suggest using generators like so:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
def resample(freq, data):
    return chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, data, freq))
```

This will probably be the fastest method there is - `map()`, `repeat()` and `chain.from_iterable()` are all implemented in C so you technically can't get any better.

As for a small explanation:

**`repeat(i, n)`** returns an iterator that repeats an item `i`, `n` times.

**`map(repeat, data, freq)`** returns an iterator that calls repeat every time on an element of `data` and an element of `freq`. Basically an iterator that returns `repeat()` iterators.

**`chain.from_iterable()`** flattens the iterator of iterators to return the end items.

No list is created on the way, so there is no overhead and as an added benefit - you can use *any* type of data and not just one char strings.

While I don't suggest it, you are able to convert it into a `list()` like so:

```
result = list(resample([1,2,3], ['a','b','c']))
```

Comment: Some quick testing appears to confirm that this is the fastest answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
def resample(freq, data):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable([el]*n for el, n in zip(data, freq))
```

Besides faster, this also has the advantage of being lazy, it returns a generator and the elements are generated step by step

Answer (score 2):

No need to create lists at all, just use a nested loop:

```
[e for i, e in enumerate(data) for j in range(freq[i])]

# ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

You can just as easily make this lazy by removing the brackets:

```
(e for i, e in enumerate(data) for j in range(freq[i]))
```